# log4cxx for CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6

I'm new to CentOS (regular Ubuntu user, but used Slackware and Gentoo a long time ago), and I'm trying to create a package for some software that depends on `log4cxx`. Unfortunately, there isn't a `log4cxx` package on CentOS 6 repository (or on EPEL). Is there any other "default" package repository for CentOS where I could find `log4cxx`, or should I just go cry into a corner and compile it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases, I perform a quick check for the package on [RPMFind.net](http://rpmfind.net/) and [rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/). If neither return a result for my distribution, chances are that a precompiled RPM is not available.

You *can* compile log4cxx from the [Fedora source repository](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=log4cxx), though.

In order to build an SRPM, you'll pretty much need to download the .srpm or .src.rpm file. From there, you can run `rpmbuild --rebuild filename.src.rpm` and the compilation process should result in a usable binary package.

I took a spare CentOS 6 system and ran the download using [this log4cxx source RPM package](ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/x/xm/xmlbeansxx/log4cxx/0.9.7/log4cxx-0.9.7-6.src.rpm) and compiled:

There was a dependency on `apr-devel` and `apr-util-devel`, but aside from that, the log4cxx built without incident.

```
# rpmbuild  --rebuild log4cxx-0.10.0-13.fc18.src.rpm 
.
.
...fancy compilation output...
.
.
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/log4cxx-0.10.0-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/log4cxx-debuginfo-0.10.0-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/log4cxx-devel-0.10.0-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

From there, install the resultant RPM's and you're good to go.